# The soft bodies are attracted to each other. Why?

Tags: soft-body

I created a scene with a rope (SoftBody) and two box with Collision only. The rope attracted to the boxes but I don't know why.

I created two videos: https://youtu.be/CWTQKD52Csg and https://youtu.be/BQJUS1dK6Vg

The Blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-33uqCH0g1cX0kcNvaC0VoW6tJxqkfVA/view?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: Apply scale on all objects participating in the simulation, then make sure that they have appropriate normals in edit mode, then make sure that you delete any bakes and physics cache.  The negative scale on the collision bodies is turning their normals inside out, which means the only non-colliding position is inside the two cubes-- an impossible position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your file and first, I fixed the normals of the wire cube.  (flip normals)
I also applied the scale to the wire cube >  (ctlr+a) apply the scale.
But what really fixed it was altering the soft body and cloth physic :
Keep thickness outer the same but set inner to 0.001

That was a kinda weird problem to solve, I've never seen anything like it before.
In fact, I think this might be useful as well, lightning strike effects or so..

Comment: Thanks, And yes, This is a useful thing but in another role.